# Bootstrap Time Input Interval 30 Minute

Tags: bootstrap-timepicker

how to make a time input form in Bootstrap AdminLTE in increments of 30 minutes,  for example when selected

00 : 30

01 : 00

01 : 30

02 : 00

02 : 30

etc...